# WordPress mobile min-height issues

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to figure out where this massive empty space is coming from when viewed from mobile on several sections and if there is a blanket fix or do I have to set a min-height:0px for each one that's messed up.

Info:
Site: http://dev.bnpwebdev.com/
Where issue occurs: Mobile (Phone / iPad ) not desktop
What I have tried:

```
.fusion-one-half .fusion-layout-column .fusion-column-last .fusion-spacing-yes .fusion-column-wrapper {
min-height:0px;}
```

I am not a css expert so all help would be appretiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your PC browser to debug your mobile website, as you would do for a normal website, by using "adaptative view", a developpement tool in almost any browser toolkit.

Active it and define a screen size : now you can reproduce your empty spaces and debug them with your favorite browser toolkit (mine is firebug :)

More generally, i think your solution will be in the "@media" sections, as they define specific behavior regarding to user screen size. Using them, you will be able to edit only the mobile part of your website.

Comment: I use chrome and this is how I found the crazy gaps. So if Im using @media what follows would be my hang up. This is what ill try based off your answer.
"@media .fusion-column-wrapper{ min-height:0px;}"

Comment: I strongly suggest you to look at your mobile website on a mobile device.
Ok, I should have say this before, but adaptative view is not fully representative of what the user will see. It is a good tool to debug a known bug, but it can also make you correct problem that never existed, and then create real problems.

Comment: I find when debugging that element.style contains the rule that gives the space. Shown in this picture [link](http://puu.sh/qoIxj/d36495b01d.png)
when I uncheck this min-height the gaps are gone. I have looked thru the style.css and cant find this almost like its generated on the page load or something.

Comment: That is currently a bad new. It implies that the element has a 'style="min-height:998px"' property, wich is often javascript or php generated. Or we were expecting CSS. To be simple, to override this with css, you'll need to use the "!important" tag on your css to be sure your custom css rules will overcome the element.style value. The correct way would be to adapt the php or javascript part that cause these spaces, but this may become a bit hard.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly this should work (Never used @media before)

"@media only screen and (max-width: px) { min-height:0px; !important}"

Comment: I would write "@media all (max-width: 800px) { min-height:0px; !important}". As i'm not confident about the difference btw "screen" and "handheld", i'd rather to define the style regarding to the window size.
Note : when using new methods, you'd rather to take 5 minutes to read the doc about it and get free code sample than trying 5 minutes to debug some kind of UFO. Less fun but way more efficient :)

Comment: Agreed, I will take your code and read thru the docs to beable to understand what its doing that way I can grasp its impact. Thank you for all your help ... the issue WAS only in debugger not on actual device!

Comment: At least one of use did joke loud :) I'm happy that everything is working.